# Второстепенный цикл tkinter python

Tags: python, многопоточность, tkinter, pthread

Мне нужно, что бы в бесконечном цикле на фоне выполнялся определенный код в момент отрисовки интерфейса, но mainloop() tkinter блокирует вообще ход всего кода и занимается своими обязанностями. Есть решения этой проблемы? Библиотека thread не подходит, mainloop() выдает ошибку если находится в потоке. Может есть какие нибудь альтернативы tkinter, где я могу сам задать обновление окна?

На сколько я знаю, pyqt работает по похожему принципу и он тоже не подходит

Comment: Вообще сам питон не особо умеет в многопоточность, он просто переключает контекст. А можете хотя бы часть кода показать, чтоб было понятно что происходит. На словах не совсем понятно (

Comment: `Библиотека thread не подходит, mainloop() выдает ошибку если находится в потоке.` - все будет работать через thread, просто нужно не mainloop в отдельный поток выносить, а наоборот - ваш код, который работает в фоне.

Answer (score 1):

Хотя если честно, по вашей теме боюсь разочаровать [вот статья которая это сделает](https://www.google.com/amp/s/habr.com/ru/amp/post/592189/)

А если говорить простыми словами, "многопоточность" питона ускоряет код только в случаях нескольких запросов

Например: мы скачиваем несколько файлов. Например архивы с удалённых серверов. Код сделает запрос и будет ждать завершения скачивания файла, а пока он его ждёт перейдёт к другому запросу и будет ждать их обоих одновременно